# How would society react to mutant zombies?

Tags: society, zombies

2020: A small asteroid lands in New York City, carrying a nasty spaceborne fungus. This pathogen turns humans and animals into "zombies." The city is quickly invaded by humanoid bags with swollen flesh, strange tumors, and appendages that come out of them. The city is quarantined so this disease cannot expand anymore. Instead of forever wandering, the infected merge together and begin to form strange structures around skyscrapers and buildings that resemble strange ¨organs,¨ with some recognizable human faces, arms, and legs. The structures and the zombies themselves are very resistant to fire and ballistic weapons. They have massive tentacles to grab and crush anything that comes close.

**How would the society react to a small zombie incident and what would happen worldwide with the media, politics, and the infected city?**

Rules: No nuclear weapons involved because the biomass can no longer expand, so the mutated creatures/zombies and their "habitat" can offer a great scientific boom, but entering this city is very dangerous.

Additional info : There is a group of survivors begging for help. Before the US government temporarily blocks the Internet in the city, these survivors upload videos and images on the Internet, complaining that the government did not evacuate the city, just sealed it with everyone inside and bombarded the airports. The quarantaine was cold and efficient in order to neutralize the threat.

Comment: Can you firstly clarify a "small asteroid lands" because asteroids are bigger than meteors, because what was its impact? If it fell like a meteor, NYC might be wiped out by that, while if it landed like a VTOL aircraft then that something was at the controls. I don't know about the rest of society, but I'd be demanding the biomass was nuked. Yes this contradicts your no nukes rule. It also depends on how quickly it takes for the great scientific boom to be known, for this to determine government action.

Comment: The asteroid was hollow and and filled with the fungus slime.The fungus can ¨consume¨ all micro organisms that touches and use them as ¨food¨,And has extremely regenerative effects and use DNA as genetic material,So it can be researched easily.And is an alien life form why destroy it instead learn from it?

Comment: By "New York City" do you mean Manhattan Island? Because NYC includes Brooklyn and Queens (on Long Island), and the Bronx (on the mainland) which would complicate quarantine. Quarantine of even Manhattan Island is difficult because [the East River is easy to swim across](http://www.theverge.com/2013/7/8/4503362/brookyln-bridge-swim-nyc-swim). There are no airports on Manhattan to bomb. As for the Internet and communicating with the outside world, it would be difficult to stop [Ham radio operators](http://www.arrl.org/internet-ham-radio) and satellite connections.

Comment: Just to clarify definitions a bit, If the object hits the earth it is a meteorite, an object from space that hits the earths surface. if a similar object is in space it's an asteroid, if it enters the earths atmosphere but burns up its a meteor.

Comment: I should alter that slightly an a asteroid is an object of rocky or metallic composition  in space with a diameter greater than 1 metre, the name for an object of similar competition of less than 1m diameter is a meteoroid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I refer you to Nigel Kneale's *The Quatermass Experiment* (BBC, 1953) for a comparable scenario. The scientist in me agrees about studying alien life. It's just that I am aware of the disastrous ecological consequences of an alien invasion (this is in the correct biological sense, not the usual science-fiction one). It really depends on the speed of knowing the benefits versus the time it takes to decide on military intervention. It would help if the alien biomass could communicate.

Comment: Yes indeded they can communicate,Some of the biomass faces can speak words but most of the time is weird nonsense and laughting/crying and can react to pain,The brains of the infected melted together inside the structures and have a rudimentary form of intelligence,Each ¨biomass colony¨ compete to get more flesh and some of the infected prey on eachother when starving.